# unable to check htaccess file in Xampp

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I'm using Codeigniter3.0.4 and now change to used mac computer and Xampp server But I got below errors.

[Tue Mar 01 22:31:29.108763 2016] [core:crit] [pid 2115] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:56770] AH00529: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dw_php-json-js/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dw_php-json-js/' is executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should establish what user XAMPP is running as. Then you should find out what groups that user is a part of by running this at the terminal:

```
groups <username>
```

Where `<username>` is the user XAMPP is running as.

Then you can check the permissions and ownership of the files mentioned in the error message:

```
# Check owner and permissions for .htaccess file:
ls -al /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dw_php-json-js/.htaccess
# Check owner and permissions of containing directory
ls -l /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dw_php-json-js/
```

An example output of such commands would be:

```
# Command: ls -l /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    521 16 Oct 12:48 version.plist
```

Which tells you the owner is root and the group is wheel. The user has `rw` (read and write) access, anybody in the group has `r` (read) access, and everybody has `r` access.

To make sure permissions are correct according to the error message you have received you need to make sure that `.htaccess` is readable by the user and the directory is executable (shown as an `x` alongside `r` and `w`).

Comment: I'm using Mac I'm just new used and I can't find .htaccess in my website direcotry

Comment: Do you know how to open a terminal and navigate to the right directory?